# How to properly install Hack and HHVM on Windows 7

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I am trying to install and configure Facebook programming language Hack and HHVM on Windows, probably Windows 7. I could not find any solution on it. I saw a Bitnami link which suggest HHVM Installers.

[source](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/hhvm/)

I have downloaded the installer files [HHVM installer files](https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/1124994/bitnami-hhvm-3.30.12-4-linux-x64-installer.run)
but it cannot run on Windows due .run extension filename. How can I achieve this using HACK and HHVM installations on Windows 7.

Comment: According to [the hhvm docs](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/windows), Windows is unfortunately not officially supported. As it also mentions, a community member (@Orvid) was configuring MSVC to build hhvm, but this was back in 2016 by the looks of it. Your best bet may be to just run a Linux VM.

Comment: @concat VM is an overkill here... WSL or Docker could be enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hack and HHVM do not support Windows. There was some work in 2015, but it doesn't seem to have continued since then.

Recent versions of HHVM do not support PHP. The Bitnami link mentions running phpmyadmin, so it looks like it's targeting an old HHVM release.

Comment: The closest thing you **can** do is to run HHVM on WSL or WSL2. You can also use Docker if you're familiar with containers.

Answer (score 0):

Hack and HHVM do not support Windows but you can try [Building and Installing HHVM on Cygwin](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM-on-Cygwin) or [Installation: Building From Source](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/building-from-source) although not recommended because they are monumental tasks.

You can also take a look at [Building and Installing HHVM](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM).

I personally gave up and installed the supported package in my Mac where ***I'm using Visual Studio Code with the HackLang plug-in for development***.